# Injecting data before creating mock component with TestBed - unit testing in angular 4

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-runner

I would like to inject data to `DeviceMarkerComponent` before running this:

```
let component: DeviceMarkerComponent;
let fixture: ComponentFixture<DeviceMarkerComponent>;
...

fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DeviceMarkerComponent);
component = fixture.componentInstance;
```

`DeviceMarkerComponent` uses variables in `ngOnInit` and I can't create the component without initializing the variables. `NgOnInit` is firing when `TestBed.CreateComponent` is called and it causes error, so I have to set these variables or modify a code which I'm testing :(

[image]

Comment: It would be helpful to know what errors it is throwing. Are there dependencies that DeviceMarkerComponent expects in its constructor that you have not provided?

Comment: I added the image

Comment: Never mind, I fixed that, I will add solution in the evening

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the testbed before creating the component.  In the configuration you can set imports, declarations, etc of what your component is using as well as pass spys.

```
let component: DeviceMarkerComponent;
let fixture: ComponentFixture<DeviceMarkerComponent>;

beforeEach(fakeAsync(() => {
   TestBed.configureTestingModule({
     declarations: [DeviceMarkerComponent],
     providers: [any providers the component uses]
     imports: [any imports component uses]
   }).compileComponents();
}));

beforeEach(() => {
   fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DeviceMarkerComponent);
   component = fixture.componentInstance;
   debugElement = fixture.debugElement;
});
```

There is also a Type alias you can use for the testbed configuration that can be helpful.
https://angular.io/api/core/testing/TestModuleMetadata

Comment: Yep, but it was still here so might as well answer.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

```js
    let component: DeviceMarkerComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<DeviceMarkerComponent>;
    ...
    const testBed = TestBed.configureTestingModule({...});
    // do anything you want to do before createComponent
    testBed.inject(AService).init();
    testBed.compileComponents();
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DeviceMarkerComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
```

the [document](https://angular.io/api/core/testing/TestBedStatic#inject) of **inject method** under the TestBedStatic class.